# How to programmatically scroll the parent listview in a nested listview page in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-listview

I am working on page with nested ListView in my flutter application. On clicking a button in a nested ListView item, I need to perform a scroll operation on the parent listview ie. scroll to particular list item in the parent list. I am using

```
shrinkWrap: true
```

and

```
physics: new ClampingScrollPhysics()
```

in the nested listview. And I am using a scrollcontroller to scroll the parent listview. All the list items are dynamic height. I have tried jumpTo and animateTo, both of them are not working.

How can I programmatically scroll the parent listview?

Comment: could you please share your code? also, try calling jumpTo() or animateTo() in a TImer  with some duration which suits you. Eg Timer(Duration(milliseconds:300),(){jumpTo()});

Comment: @JagrajSingh Hey.. i have tried your solution..Now its scrolling some distance and comes back to the same position again..Now iam using the sliverlist as the parent.and the controller is assigned to the chilld listview of the SliverChildListDelegate.

Comment: Please share the code